# Chrome PlugIn not working under linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, png

I wrote a chrome Extension that works just fine for windows chrome users. But at least one Linux user receives the message

```
"Symbol "googleFilter.png" konnte nicht für Browseraktion geladen werden." Chromium Version 31.0.1650.57 (235101) mit Arch Linux
```

(Translated should be something like

```
 "Symbol "googleFilter.png" could not be used as a browseraction." Chromium Version 31.0.1650.57 (235101) with Arch Linux
```

That symbol is the Extensions-Symbol. Are there any file format limitations on the Linux-Version of Chrome?

Just for information: Url to the Plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google+-filter/edknapjhmlocokbpbihilmjmfmmddhop if you want to look at the image

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to answer myself (again)
It was a case sensitive issue. The filename was "googlefilter.png". Which was just fine for windows, but not surprisingly a problem for *nix - environments.